# Confusion about Mod functor in Institutions

Tags: logic, category-theory, model-theory

**TL;DR:** "It is also fundamental that sentences translate in the same direction as the change of notation, whereas models translate in the opposite direction." (Goguen, *Institutions: Abstract model theory for specification and programming*, p. 101). Why?

Institutions are typically defined as 4-tuples $I = (\mathbf{Sign},\textit{sen},\mathbf{Mod},\models)$ (see e.g. Goguen, Diaconescu, or Meseguer, which is the one I'm spending the most time on), where in particular $\mathbf{Mod}$ is a functor $\mathbf{Mod} : \mathbf{Sign}^{\textit{op}} \to \mathbf{Cat}$ (or also sometimes defined as $\mathbf{Mod}$ is a functor $\mathbf{Mod} : \mathbf{Sign} \to \mathbf{Cat}^{\textit{op}}$).

I cannot for the life of me figure out how it works, and why we're working with duals (a.k.a. opposites).

My thinking thus far has been: We two signatures, $\Sigma$ and $\Sigma'$, a signature morphism $H:\Sigma\to\Sigma'$, and... a $\Sigma'$-Model $M'$? Why not a $\Sigma$-Model $M$? But ignoring that question for now, say $M' = (\{a,b,c,abc,baca\},\{f^{\mathcal{A}'},g^{\mathcal{A}'}\})$ ($a$ through $c$ being constant symbols and f and g function symbols, with the superscript ($\mathcal{A}'=\{a,b,c,abc,baca\}$ **Edit: This is not what underlying sets look like, and this faulty assumption is what caused my confusion.**) referring to their particular interpretations). How do we transform this into a $\Sigma$-model $M$? We can't translate $\mathcal{A}'$ into $\mathcal{A} = \{1,2,3,123,2131\}$, because our signature morphism is in the wrong direction, and the same goes for the function symbols. We can, yes, if we already knew the corresponding function symbols in $\Sigma$ (say $6$ and $7$) associate to them the interpretation associated with $\textit{sen}(H)(6) = f$ and $\textit{sen}(H)(7) = g$, respectively (though I'm also not sure how that works), but aside from that I'm incredibly confused, and been so for many hours. I love the generality of it all but apparently my brain / zero mathematical maturity can't handle it.

Any help would be *much* appreciated.

Thanks and happy holidays!

*Diaconescu, Răzvan*, Institution-independent model theory, Studies in Universal Logic. Basel: Birkhäuser (ISBN 978-3-7643-8707-5/pbk). xi, 376 p. (2008). [ZBL1144.03001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1144.03001).

*Goguen, Joseph A.; Burstall, Rod M.*, [**Institutions: Abstract model theory for specification and programming**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/147508.147524), J. Assoc. Comput. Mach. 39, No. 1, 95-146 (1992). [ZBL0799.68134](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0799.68134).

*Goguen, J. A.; Burstall, R. M.*, Introducing institutions, Logics of programs, Workshop, Pittsburgh/PA 1983, Lect. Notes Comput. Sci. 164, 221-256 (1984). [ZBL0543.68021](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0543.68021).

*Meseguer, José*, General logics, Logic colloq. ’87, Proc. Colloq., Granada/Spain 1987, Stud. Logic Found. Math. 129, 275-329 (1989). [ZBL0691.03001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0691.03001).

Comment: In the usual model theory, *signatures* are languages. *Sentences* are expression of the language (without free variables). *Models* are mathematical objects (structures) used to interpret the language and $\vDash$ is the *satisfaction* relation between a model $M$ and a sentence $\varphi$ such that $M \vDash \varphi$ **iff** the sentence holds (is TRUE) in the structure $M$.

Comment: In Diaconescu's approach they are expressed in category theory language.

Comment: The functor $\text {Mod}^I$ is a functor that maps every *signature* $\Sigma$ (an object in $\text {Sig}^I$ is a *signature*) into the category whose objects are the models of $\Sigma$.

Comment: Yes, that part I understand (third comment), but it's $\text{Mod}^I$ mapping signature morphisms that confuses me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you have a signature morphism $H:\Sigma\to \Sigma'$ and $M$ is a $\Sigma'$-model.  Then you can define a $\Sigma$-model $H^*M$ with the same underlying set as $M$, where for each $\sigma\in\Sigma$ the function or relation $\sigma_{H^*M}$ is defined to be $H(\sigma)_M$.  In other words, to interpret a symbol $\sigma$ in $\Sigma$ on $M$, you just use the interpretation of $H(\sigma)$, and in this way $M$ turns into a $\Sigma$-model.

In this way, a morphism $H:\Sigma\to\Sigma'$ gives a way of turning $\Sigma'$-models into $\Sigma$-models, and it is easy to check that this also turns $\Sigma'$-homomorphisms into $\Sigma$-homomorphisms and thus induces a functor $\mathbf{Mod}(\Sigma')\to\mathbf{Mod}(\Sigma)$.  This makes $\mathbf{Mod}$ a functor $\mathbf{Sign}\to\mathbf{Cat}^{op}$: it sends an object $\Sigma$ to the category $\mathbf{Mod}(\Sigma)$, and a morphism $H:\Sigma\to\Sigma'$ to a functor $\mathbf{Mod}(\Sigma')\to\mathbf{Mod}(\Sigma)$ and you can check that this preserves identities and composition.

(To be clear, here I am assuming you are working with the "standard" institution of classical model theory.  The point of institutions is to make an *abstract* definition which captures similar formal behavior to classical and other model theories.  So in a general institution, "models" don't have to be anything like models in classical model theory as I described here; they just have to (together with the rest of the 4-tuple) satisfy the definition of an institution.  The story above is *motivation* for why instutitions are defined they way they are, with $\mathbf{Mod}$ being contravariant.)

Comment: It seems like I had the (apparently faulty) assumption that the underlying set is dependent upon the signature. So... that's not the case?

Comment: I don't even know what that means.  A model can have any underlying set at all, as long as you also provide interpretations of everything in the signature for that set.

Comment: Well I thought the underlying set of a $\Sigma$-model would always have to be a subset of $\textit{sen}(\Sigma)$. So, to reiterate, that's not true?

Comment: Correct, that is not true.  The elements of a $\Sigma$-model typically have nothing to do with sentences.

Comment: Okay that changes everything. It makes sense now. Thank you so much!